# What does '<' mean when defining a class?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I have this line of Ruby code generated by rails:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
```

What does `<` mean?

Comment: Seems like there are answers enough, however I didn't see a reference to the official Ruby doc yet. So here you go: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance

Answer (score 6):

`<` is used for **Inheritance**. In Ruby, a class can only inherit from a single other class.

> class PostsController < ApplicationController

in above line of code `PostsController` (child-class) is inherits from `ApplicationController` parent-class.

**In Rails:**

`Action Controllers` are the core of a web request in Rails. By default, only the `ApplicationController` in a Rails application inherits from `ActionController::Base`. All other controllers inherit from `ApplicationController`. This gives you one class to configure things such as request forgery protection and filtering of sensitive request parameters.

for more info :

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance
- http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Answer (score 1):

It means that `PostsController` definition starts by having everything in `ApplicationController`. while the rest of the definitions will add/replace members/attributes to `PostsController`.

Comment: Using the term "extend" in your sense should be avoided in the context of Ruby because it means something else. It is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying there is: "Declare a new class called **PostsController** and inherit the behaviour from **ApplicationsController** to be used in **PostsController**".

Basically < is used for Inheritance

More info [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `<` indicates [inheritance](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/inheritance.html). Basically, this means that `PostsController` will have everything `ApplicationController` has, except for it's [private members](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/accesscontrol.html). However, you can [override methods](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_overriding_methods.html) in the subclass to change the behavior of the methods inherited from the superclass.